# How to get only month and year picker in Android calendar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using DatePickerDialog with AlertDIalog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT (in this case I'm getting the desired views) . The problem is , it only works with Android O and above  .For < Android O I'm forced to use DatePickerDialog without the AlertDIalog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT , here I am unable to get a calendar with only month and year.

Answer (score 0):

use this library

[Date Picker](https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker)

then build your date picker like this

```
new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(this)
            .bottomSheet()
            .curved()
            .displayMinutes(false)
            .displayHours(false)
            .displayDays(false)
            .displayMonth(true)
            .displayYears(true)
            .displayDaysOfMonth(false)
            .display();
```